# Why does Rails not correctly unescape escaped strings in my fixtures?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a weird thing going on where I tried to update to Ruby 2.3.1, but now a test fails. The test which fails seems like the broken data is in the Rails fixtures, as opposed to being a real failure.

In the fixture, I have:

```
one:
  name: "\u30C6\u30B9\u30C8"
```

When I look at this value in the console, it seems like it has been double-escaped:

```
irb(main):001:0> Organisation.first.name
  Organisation Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "organisations".* FROM "organisations"  ORDER BY "organisations"."id" ASC LIMIT 1
=> "\\u30C6\\u30B9\\u30C8"
```

This is also exactly what I saw when I debugged the tests themselves.

Known so far:

- If I downgrade back to to Ruby 2.1.2, I see the proper unescaped value.
- If I downgrade to Ruby 2.2.2, the issue still occurs.
- If I load the *exact same file* using `YAML.load` on Ruby 2.3.1, I see the proper unescaped value.
- If I create a brand new Rails application and copy the exact same fixture lines over, I see the proper unescaped value.

What could possibly be going on here? Is some other gem interfering with parsing YAML, but only when loaded using whatever Rails is using to load fixtures? How does Rails load fixtures which makes it not work even though `YAML.load` appears to work fine?

Rails is version 4.2.6.

Other gems in use:

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.2.0'

gem 'sqlite3'
gem 'mysql2', platforms: %w( ruby )

group :development do
  gem 'capistrano', git: 'git://github.com/trejkaz/capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rbenv'
end

gem 'uglifier'
gem 'execjs'
gem 'therubyracer'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'byebug'
end

gem 'rails3-restful-authentication', require: 'restful_authentication'
gem 'strip_attributes'
gem 'dynamic_form'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'acts_as_list'
gem 'jquery-tokeninput-rails'
gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'jquery-ui-rails'
gem 'exception_notification', '~> 4.0.0'
gem 'syck', '~> 1.0.0'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'simplecov'
  gem 'ci_reporter_minitest'
  gem 'mocha'
  gem 'metric_fu'
  gem 'flog', '~> 4.3.2'
end
```

Digging inside ActiveRecord, the low-level fixture reading code is definitely doing the wrong thing somehow...

```
irb(main):014:0> ActiveRecord::FixtureSet::File.open('test/fixtures/organisations.yml') { |fh| fh.each { |fixture_name, row| puts fixture_name; puts row } }
one
{"name"=>"\\u30C6\\u30B9\\u30C8"}
=> [["one", {"name"=>"\\u30C6\\u30B9\\u30C8"}]]
```

Behaviour of loading YAML differs depending on whether you just load irb, or use the rails console... So it does seem like something else in the environment messes up reading YAML somehow. :(

```
$ irb
irb(main):001:0> require 'yaml'
=> true
irb(main):002:0> YAML.load_file('test/fixtures/organisations.yml')
=> {"six"=>{"name"=>"テスト"}}
irb(main):003:0> 

$ bundle exec rails console
Loading development environment (Rails 4.2.6)
irb(main):001:0> YAML.load_file('test/fixtures/organisations.yml')
=> {"six"=>{"name"=>"\\u30C6\\u30B9\\u30C8"}}
irb(main):002:0>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would blame syck - this is the yaml parser from pre ruby 1.9.3 (although it was I believe still available in later versions just not the default) made available as a gem for those who depend on it. To quote the "problems" section from the gem's readme

> Monkeypatches the crap out of everything

Unless you have some very particular legacy code you almost certainly don't need it. Its replacement (psych) is part of the ruby standard library.

Comment: I had tried to remove it before but tests failed because the new parser wasn't handling my YAML exactly the same as Syck. :/  Guess I'm going to have to put in more work to figure out how to make Psych handle our existing YAML files.